# XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

I'm trying to insert rows into a table using a select from XML. I think I'm close. Where am I going wrong?

```
declare @xmldata xml;
set @xmldata = '<Database>
                  <PurchaseDetails>
                    <PurchaseDetail>
                      <Upc>72594206916</Upc>
                      <Quantity>77</Quantity>
                      <PurchaseDate>9/2010</PurchaseDate>
                      <PurchaseCity>Dallas</PurchaseCity>
                      <PurchaseState>TX</PurchaseState>
                    </PurchaseDetail>
                    <PurchaseDetail>
                      <Upc>72594221854</Upc>
                      <Quantity>33</Quantity>
                      <PurchaseDate>12/2013</PurchaseDate>
                      <PurchaseCity>Nashville</PurchaseCity>
                      <PurchaseState>TN</PurchaseState>
                    </PurchaseDetail>
                  </PurchaseDetails>
                </Database>'

insert into PurchaseDetails
(Upc, Quantity, PurchaseDate, PurchaseCity, PurchaseState)
select
    x.Rec.value('Upc','char(11)'),
    x.Rec.value('Quantity','int'),
    x.Rec.value('PurchaseDate','varchar(7)'),
    x.Rec.value('PurchaseCity','varchar(50)'),
    x.Rec.value('PurchaseState','char(2)')
from @xmlData.nodes('//Database/PurchaseDetails/PurchaseDetail') as x(Rec)
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A co-worker had tackled a similar problem before. Here is what we came up with. NOT intuitive!

```
insert into PurchaseDetails
(Upc, Quantity, PurchaseDate, PurchaseCity, PurchaseState)
select
    pd.value('Upc[1]','char(11)'),
    pd.value('Quantity[1]','int'),
    pd.value('PurchaseDate[1]','varchar(7)'),
    pd.value('PurchaseCity[1]','varchar(50)'),
    pd.value('PurchaseState[1]','char(2)')
from @xmlData.nodes('//Database/PurchaseDetails') as x(Rec)
cross apply @xmlData.nodes('//Database/PurchaseDetails/PurchaseDetail') as i(pd)
```

Comment: Works perfectly; any idea what the reason behind the [1] is?

Comment: @jvenema, The reason behind the problem is that XQuery always returns a collection if you don't use [] at the end of it. So in your case pd.Value('sth') returns a collection, although nodes function in the From clause deliver only one row to the Value function  By the way The Mikel's answer is also correct and more to the point.

Comment: Any idea what the cross apply is doing? x(Rec) isn't referenced in the query, but taking that piece out makes it not work.

Comment: This was surprisingly hard to find, works great..I don't understand how it works for unknown amount of records, is it recursive?

Answer (score 42):

Try this!
query() then value()
run this in SQL Server and 100% worked
put a dot (.) first then the child tag.
PurchaseDetail tag exists 2 times so the dot (.) replaces the first and the second tag.
The dot can prevent using of [1] on XQuery.
The dot represents the first and the second PurchaseDetail tags.

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseDetails(Upc, Quantity, PurchaseDate, PurchaseCity, PurchaseState)
SELECT col.query('./Upc').value('.', 'char(11)'),
    col.query('./Quantity').value('.', 'int'),
    col.query('./PurchaseDate').value('.', 'varchar(7)'),
    col.query('./PurchaseCity').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
    col.query('./PurchaseState').value('.', 'char(2)')
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/Database/PurchaseDetails/PurchaseDetail') as ref(col)
```

It is more simplified query so far.
See if it works

Answer (score 25):

```
insert into PurchaseDetails(Upc, Quantity, PurchaseDate, PurchaseCity, PurchaseState)
select T.X.value('(Upc/text())[1]', 'char(11)'),
       T.X.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'int'),
       T.X.value('(PurchaseDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(7)'),
       T.X.value('(PurchaseCity/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       T.X.value('(PurchaseState/text())[1]', 'char(2)')
from @xmlData.nodes('/Database/PurchaseDetails/PurchaseDetail') as T(X)
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and efficient solution that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
select
    x.Rec.query('./Upc').value('.','char(11)')
    ,x.Rec.query('./Quantity').value('.','int')
    ,x.Rec.query('./PurchaseDate').value('.','varchar(7)')
    ,x.Rec.query('./PurchaseCity').value('.','varchar(50)')
    ,x.Rec.query('./PurchaseState').value('.','char(2)')
from @xmlData.nodes('/Database/PurchaseDetails/PurchaseDetail') as x(Rec)
```

Answer (score 10):

Struggling with a similar problem, and found that @birdus's answer didn't work if you have additional layers of nesting in your xml that you were referencing in your XQuery, e.g. supposing a slightly different XML shape, if you had

```
T.x.value('PurchasePlace/PurchaseCity[1]','varchar(50)')
```

you would still get the singleton error. Though @birdus's solution does work for this specific case a more generally applicable solution that combines the best of @birdus's & @Mikael-Eriksson's solution is to do:

```
insert into PurchaseDetails(Upc, Quantity, PurchaseDate, PurchaseCity, PurchaseState)
select T.X.value('(Upc)[1]', 'char(11)'),
T.X.value('(Quantity)[1]', 'int'),
T.X.value('(PurchaseDate)[1]', 'varchar(7)'),
T.X.value('(PurchaseCity)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
T.X.value('(PurchaseState)[1]', 'char(2)')
from @xmlData.nodes('/Database/PurchaseDetails/PurchaseDetail') as T(X)
```

This combine's @birdus's omission of `/text()`, which is superfluous, but adds @Mikael-Eriksson's parentheses around the element selector, to allow multiple element selectors as in my modified example which becomes:

```
T.x.value('(PurchasePlace/PurchaseCity)[1]','varchar(50)')
```

The *reason* for this, that a few have asked about, is not that @birdus's version returns something other than a singleton in any of the examples discussed here, but that it *might*. Per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/guidelines-for-using-xml-data-type-methods#singleton-checks):

> Location steps, function parameters, and operators that require singletons will return an error if the compiler cannot determine whether a singleton is guaranteed at run time.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but for what it's worth, I removed the `/text()`, and it caused a major lag in time in my data set.  With `/text()`, it took 25 seconds to insert 55K records into the table.  Without `/text()`, I stopped the query at 53 seconds because the additional time wasn't worth it.

Comment: Wrapping the xpath in parenthesis worked for me, followed by the first instance attribute:  XmlPayLoad.value( '(/root/child/wantedvalue)[1]','varchar' )

Answer (score 5):

To address the question of *why* the need for the positional predicate (i.e., `[1]`) within the XQuery string literal, like @pbz indicated, a singleton is required and therefore must be guaranteed. To add more substance to @pbz's answer, see below.

Per Microsoft's [SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017):

> > In the following example, an XML instance is stored in a variable of xml type. The value() method retrieves the ProductID attribute value
> >     from the XML. The value is then assigned to an int variable.
>
> ```
> DECLARE @myDoc xml  
> DECLARE @ProdID int  
> SET @myDoc = '<Root>  
> <ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
> <Features>  
>   <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
>   <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
> </Features>  
> </ProductDescription>  
> </Root>'  
>
> SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )  
> SELECT @ProdID
> ```
>
> Value 1 is returned as a result.
>
> *Although there is only one ProductID attribute in the XML instance, **the static typing rules require you to explicitly specify that the path expression returns a singleton**. Therefore, the additional `[1]`
>   is specified at the end of the path expression.* For more information
>   about static typing, see [XQuery and Static Typing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-and-static-typing?view=sql-server-2017).

Following that link then leads us to:

> As mentioned earlier, *type inference frequently **infers a type that is
>   broader than what the user knows** about the type of the data that is
>   being passed. In these cases, the user has to rewrite the query.* Some
>   typical cases include the following:
>
> ...
>
> - *The type **infers a higher cardinality** than what the data actually    contains*. This occurs frequently, because *the xml data type **can
>
>     contain more than one top-level element**, and an XML schema collection 
>     cannot constrain this. In order to reduce the static type and
>
>     **guarantee that there is indeed at most one value** being passed, you
>
>     should **use the positional predicate `[1]`***. For example, to add 1 to the 
>     value of the attribute c of the element b under the top-level a
>     element, you must write `(/a/b/@c)[1]+1`. Additionally, the DOCUMENT
>     keyword can be used together with an XML schema collection.